# Migrated from SQL Server CE to SQL Server, now WebSecurity causing SQL Timeouts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, asp.net-webpages

We have a site we built using ASP.Net Webpages

I recently migrated the database from SQL Server CE to SQL Server 2014. I did this using the SQL Server Compact Toolbox on my local machine, then attached the `.mdf` file to our website hosts SQL Server instance.

Everything worked great and the site seemed to be running fine. However, shortly after, I began to notice intermittent exceptions which like this one:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(IDatabase db, String userTableName, String userNameColumn, String userIdColumn, String userName)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
>   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.GetUserId(String userName)
>   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.get_CurrentUserId()
>   at ASP._Page_Default_cshtml.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3() in e:\web\givetoru\Default.cshtml:line 118
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__9(TextWriter tw)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
>   at ASP._Page__SiteLayout_cshtml.Execute() in e:\web\givetoru_SiteLayout.cshtml:line 184
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer)
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
>
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>
> ClientConnectionId:4f57f963-05e1-4429-946b-504e59e13050
>   Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

After doing some digging, it looks like it may have to do with calls to `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity` class like this one:

```
WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might cause this issue? Do I need to do anything special to my DB to prevent these timeouts?

Update 20170303 922AM CT

Here are my connection strings (with sensitive data redacted) for reference:

```
<add name="StarterSiteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.ProductModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:*****;initial catalog=*****;integrated security=False;Connection Timeout=30;user id=*****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="StarterSite" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=*****;Integrated Security=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName=
"System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is the line from my `_AppStart.cshtml` file that initializes the WebSecurity DB connection:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("StarterSite", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: false);
```

Comment: Just a quick idea: WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity handles the SimpleMembershipProvider. Per default, this can use an entirely different connection string than your regular data access code. So you could check if there are two different connection strings in use, and maybe one was not updated when migrating to the full SQL Server database.

Comment: This looks like a general timeout issue. If you restart SQL Server does the the timeout issue go away? Ie. Does the issue occur only after SQL Server has been running for a while?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a normal connection issue to the SQL Server. As your application works in general, I assume that your issue could be that you might use different connection strings for your regular data access code and the authentication with `SimpleMembershipProvider`, causing the issue only when any authentication related data is queried from the database:

As mentioned in my comment below your question, `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity`, where the exception occurs, handles authentication with the `SimpleMembershipProvider`. The connection string used for this can be an entirely different one than you would use for your regular data access code, e.g. an Entity Framework `DataContext`.

So, the way you describe it, I think it is very likely that you are using two different connection strings for `SimpleMembershipProvider` and your EF `DataContext` (or whatever you use for your data access needs) and maybe the one for the `SimpleMembershipProvider` was not updated when migrating to the full SQL Server database.

I hope this at least leads you in the right direction. Else, maybe you want to share your web.config and in particular the complete Membership and ConnectionString configuration. Make sure not to post any sensitive data, though :)

**Update:**

The connection strings you posted seem fine and identical. I missed one bit in your exception: It says `Timeout expired` while, in case if it really was a connection timeout, it would say `Connection timeout expired` (at least in .NET Framework 4.5 or newer, IIRC).

So you should check if you might run into a query performance issue. Do you have an index on `UserName` in your custom user table, as this is what was queried for according to the StackTrace? Whereas I admit it seems unlikely a single query in a user table without any complex joins could run longer than 30 sec, even if there was no index. But possibly you run into a database lock sometimes.

So what you could do next is to attach SQL Server Profiler to your database and let it run until an exception like the above appears in your application. Then check if there was any long running query executed at this time in Profiler.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I have updated my question to include the connection strings.

Comment: @TodBirdsall I just noticed I missed an important little bit in your exception: it says `Timeout expired` versus it should say `Connection timeout expired` if it was a connection timeout. Although I currently don't remember which framework version did add this distinction in the error message. Are you at least on .NET 4.5? If so, I'm sure it would say connection timeout if it was one. So it could be the issue you are facing might be a slow executing query. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I will give the profiler a try if the issue continues.